# What is "(Default)" key every Windows Registry Key

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regedit

I saw by opening `regedit` that every registry key has a "(Default)" value filled with "value not set".

This key is always the first.

So I've few questions:

1. Why does this Key exist?
2. What is this key used for?
3. Can it be overridden / is it a good idea to?

Comment: Registry "values" are not "keys". The "keys" are the things represented in the Registry Editor by folder icons.

Comment: Default values are not always empty. The default value can be used for anything any other value can be. It is up to the software using those registry values to determine what they mean and how they are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What is the Windows `(Default)` Registry Key?

**Why does this Key exist?**

> The original 16-bit registry didn’t have named values. All it had were keys, and associated with each key was a single piece of data: a string. The functions that operated on this data were `RegSetValue` and `RegQueryValue`, which explains why those functions (1) don’t have a `lpValue` parameter and (2) set and retrieve only string data. Because back in the 16-bit world, that’s all you had.

> In the conversion to Win32, the registry gained new capabilities, such as storing data in formats beyond simple strings, and storing multiple pieces of data under a single key, using a name to distinguish them.

> What used to be called simply “the value of a registry key” (for since there was only one, there was no need to give it a name) now goes by the special name the default value: It’s the value whose name is null.

**What is this key used for?**

> There’s nothing particularly special about the default value aside from its unusual name. A named value need not exist, and if it exists, the data type could be anything. Similarly, the default value need not exist, and its type can be anything. At this point, it’s just a value with a strange name.

**Can it be overridden / is it a good idea to?**

There is no point in doing so. See above.

Source [Why do registry keys have a default value? - The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080118-00/?p=23773)

Comment: Registry "values" are not "keys". Please stop confusing the two terms.

Comment: @kreemoweet I never said they were. In any case keys can have values.